# PHP Simple Form Validation

Tags: php, validation

Ok, what I'm trying to achieve is a very simple form validation like the following.

1. Name: [required, min length: 2, max length: 255]
2. Email: [required, min length: 3, max length: 255, valid email format]
3. Date of Birth: [optional, format: dd/mm/yyyy]

However, once i click submit (either if the fields are empty or filled) I get all of my echoed errors displayed on a blank page.

**"name must be at least 2 charactersname is requiredemail must be at least 3 charactersinvalid emailemail cannot be left empty"**

My code so far:

*index.php*

```
<form method="post" action="confirm.php">
Name:<input type="text" name="name" />
email:<input type="text" name="email" />
DOB:<input type="date" name="dob" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

and

*confirm.php*

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['$name'];
$email = $_POST['$email'];
$dob = $_POST['$dob'];

$namelen = strlen($email);
$emaillen = strlen($email);
$max = 255;
$minname = 2;
$minemail = 3;

if($namelen<$minname){
    echo"name must be at least 2 characters";
}
elseif($namelen>$max){
    echo"name must be less than 255 characters";
}

if(empty($name)){
    echo"name is required";
}
else{
    continue;
}

if($emaillen<$minemail){
    echo"email must be at least 3 characters";
}
elseif($emaillen>$max){
    echo"email must be less than 255 characters";
}

if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    continue;
}
else{
    echo"invalid email";
}

if(empty($email)){
    echo"email cannot be left empty";
}
else{
    continue;
}

?>
```

Help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You have not written anything to make it stop after checking the first and second error.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with those `continue;` statements?

Comment: Reposted the question.

Comment: if the field is empty, echo"something", otherwise continue.

Comment: how can i make it stop after checking the first and second error?

Comment: @user2955356 I may sound rude but, honestly, learn programming first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following in your code:

```
$name = $_POST['$name'];
$email = $_POST['$email'];
$dob = $_POST['$dob'];
```

You're basically trying to access undefined indexes. Remove the extra `$` from the key names:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$dob = $_POST['dob'];
```

Then, further below, you have some conditions like this:

```
if(condition == true) {
    continue;
} else {
    // do something
}
```

It's actually not necessary, and you could change it to:

```
if(!condition) {
    // do something
}
```

Also, it's better to push the error messages into an array (`$errors`) and then loop through it and display the error messages. It might help organize your code a bit better.

Here's how the modified code looks like:

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $dob = $_POST['dob'];

    $namelen = strlen($name);
    $emaillen = strlen($email);
    $max = 255;
    $minname = 2;
    $minemail = 3;

    if($namelen < $minname){
        $errors[] = "name must be at least 2 characters";
    } elseif($namelen > $max){
        $errors[] = "name must be less than 255 characters";
    }

    if($emaillen < $minemail){
        $errors[] = "email must be at least 3 characters";
    } elseif($emaillen > $max){
        $errors[] = "email must be less than 255 characters";
    }

    if(empty($name)){
        $errors[] = "name is required";
    }

    if(empty($email)){
        $errors[] = "email cannot be left empty";
    }

    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $errors[] = "invalid email";
    }

    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo "<li>$error</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";

}
```

It could still be improved, but however, this should get you started!

Answer (score 0):

You have not written anything to make it stop after checking the first and second error.

Also, `continue` makes no sense in an `if` statement (see http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php).

Lastly, the page is "blank" because there is no HTML output, just the text. You might want to [redirect the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php) back to the form page with the error messages instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = $_POST['$name'];
$email = $_POST['$email'];
$dob = $_POST['$dob'];
```

That's wrong, you have to use

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$dob = $_POST['dob'];
```

Also you may want to change the line

```
$namelen = strlen($email);
```

to

```
$namelen = strlen($name);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You have eagle eyes, i went through it a couple of times and didn't spot the $namelen

Answer (score 0):

check if(!empty($_POST[fieldname]))
and then redirected it displaying a alert in javascript that the fields are empty