# How to add a simple validation in PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, validation

How can i add a simple validation which checks if every input is not empty?

I'm just aiming a simple validation which shows an error in the php file if at least 1 form is empty. and proceed to add the input into the database when everything is completely filled up. I already set the variable for every input in the form field of the html form.

HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>FEATHER FRIENDS PIZZA SHOP</title>
</head>
<img src="pics/logo.png">
<style>
    img {
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
        width:100%;
    }

    input[type=text], select {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 12px 20px;
        margin: 8px 0;
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    input[type=submit] {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
        padding: 14px 20px;
        margin: 8px 0;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 4px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    input[type=reset] {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #bfac2c;
        color: white;
        padding: 14px 20px;
        margin: 8px 0;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 4px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    input[type=reset]:hover {
        background-color: #c43848;
    }

    input[type=submit]:hover {
        background-color: #c43848;
    }

    div {
        background-image: url('pics/bg.png');
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        padding: 100px;
    }
    body {
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #f6f6d4;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
    </style>
    <div>
<body>
<img src="pics/pizza.png">
<form action="http://localhost/insert.php" method="post">

<img src="pics/name.png">   
<input type="text" id="fname" name="name" placeholder="Your full name...">

<img src="pics/size.png">   
<select id="size" name="size">
    <option value="small">Small</option>
    <option value="medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="large">Large</option>
    <option value="extra large">Extra Large</option>
</select>

<img src="pics/crust.png">  
<select id="crust" name="crust">
    <option value="pan">Pan</option>
    <option value="thin">Thin</option>
    <option value="stuffed">Stuffed</option>
    <option value="handtossed">Hand-Tossed</option>
    <option value="deepdish">Deep Dish</option>
</select>

<img src="pics/garnish.png">
<input type="text" id="garnish" name="garnish" placeholder="Write your choices here! Ex: Pepperoni, Cheese, Bacon, Mushroom">

<img src="pics/address.png">
<input type="text" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Where should we deliver?">

<img src="pics/contact.png">
<input type="text" id="contact" name="contact" placeholder="What is your contact number?">

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="reset" value="Reset your Order?">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pizza");

if($link === false){
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['name']);
$size = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['size']);
$crust = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['crust']);
$garnish = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['garnish']);
$address = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['address']);
$contact = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['contact']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO deliver (name, size, crust, garnish, address, contact) 
VALUES ('$name', '$size', '$crust', '$garnish', '$address', '$contact')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
echo "Data successfully Saved.";
} else{
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790601/php-simple-form-validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple line of code to check if all the form fields are populated:

```
<?php

    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pizza");

    if($link === false){
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['name']);
    $size = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['size']);
    $crust = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['crust']);
    $garnish = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['garnish']);
    $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['address']);
    $contact = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['contact']);


    /*check if all the fields are not empty*/
    if( $name != "" && $size != "" && $crust != "" && $garnish != "" && $address != "" && $contact != "") {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO deliver (name, size, crust, garnish, address, contact) VALUES ('$name', '$size', '$crust', '$garnish', '$address', '$contact')";

        if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
            echo "Data successfully Saved.";
        } else{
            echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
        }

    } else {
        echo "Form incomplete";
    }

    mysqli_close($link);

?>
```